Running Python Script through Crontab doesn't work
So I have written a script to summarize a few newsletters and send them to me in Telegram. The script itself works perfectly. Now I tried to run this script every morning at 7 via crontab on a Ubunutu Server. The Log File looks fine, every print() I used in the script shows up normally without errors, but the it doesn't send the message.
My Crontab command:
00 12 * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python3 /root/data/App/Briefing/main.py >> /home/main.log &2>1

Python scripts:
main.py
import ai as AiHandler
import mail as MailHandler
import send as Telegram
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
def start():
    files = MailHandler.scanEmails()
    files = AiHandler.summarize(files)

    print(files)

    data = pd.read_csv('checkpoint.csv', sep=';')
    checkpoint = createMsg(data)

    s = f"morgentliches Briefing vom {date.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")}".replace(".", "\\.")

    s += "\n\n\n ☕️ *Die* *Lage* *am* *Morgen* *\\-* *Spiegel*\n\n\n" + createMsg(pd.read_csv('spiegel.csv', sep=';'))

    s += "\n\n\n  *Berlin* *\\-* *Tagesspiegel* *Checkpoint*\n\n\n" + checkpoint

    s += "\n\n\n *Tech* *Update* *\\-* *ManagerMagazin* \n\n\n" + createMsg(pd.read_csv('manager.csv', sep=';'))  


    Telegram.sendMessage(s)
    

def createMsg(data):

    s = ""

    for i in range(5):

        thema = data['Thema'][i].replace('*', '\\*')
        zsm = data['Zusammenfassung'][i].replace('*', '\\*')

        s += "\t" + "*" + thema + "*" + "\n"
        s += zsm + "\n"
    
    s = s.replace("-", "\\-")
    s = s.replace(".", "\\.")
    s = s.replace("(", "\\(")
    s = s.replace(")", "\\)")
    #s = s.replace("*", "\\*")
    s = s.replace("!", "\\!")

    return s
start()


send.py
import telebot

def sendMessage(msg):
    bot = telebot.TeleBot("XXXXXX")
    bot.send_message(chat_id="@morgenbriefing", text=msg, parse_mode="MarkdownV2")

I tried adding DISPLAY:=0 to the crontab command but it didnt help

Of course DISPLAY=:0 doesn't help, it makes sense (though only very little sense) if your script attempts to display something on the first display over X11, but your script doesn't seem to have that particular problem.

Cron job not running has some hints for troubleshooting, though if you can see that your script actually runs, the problem is probably elsewhere.

The cron job runs at 12, not at 7.

If I were Telegram I'd block anyone who uses emoji with such reckless abandon, but then I guess that's why I'm not on Telegram at all in the first place.

I see only one print() in code - so it doesn't check all code. maybe you should add more print() to check every step. And maybe it will need try/except to catch error and write to standard output. And first you  should use /full/path/to/checkpoint.csv because cronjob may run code from different folder and it may search file in different folder.

I took your code from Stackoverflow and now I can send messages :)

are you sure paths/environment are set up appropriately. ? also writing a log to /home/  .... really not a good idea, this should be going into a user's account or /tmp.
